# How to Duplicate Column in same table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to duplicate a column hotelid , and then i want to make a couples that begin with the same letter,

```
select cast (hotelid as int) as hotelid1 , cast (hotelid as int) as hotelid2
    from hotel
    where (postcode BETWEEN 1500 ANd 1999) or
    ( postcode BETWEEN 3000 and 3499) 
    and  (hotelid2 > hotelid1 )
     and ( LEFT(hotelid1, 1) like  LEFT(hotelid2, 1))
```

how i can use the new lines  in `where conditions` ?

Comment: hotelid1 and hotelid2 will be the same and condition  (hotelid2 > hotelid1 ) will return zero result

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses `HAVING` for that

```
SELECT cast(hotelid as UNSIGNED ) as hotelid1 , cast(hotelid as UNSIGNED ) as hotelid2
from hotel
where (postcode BETWEEN 1500 ANd 1999) or
( postcode BETWEEN 3000 and 3499) 
HAVING  (hotelid2 > hotelid1 )
 and ( LEFT(hotelid1, 1) like  LEFT(hotelid2, 1))
```